# Simple single char array encryption needs an artificially long array to work?

Tags: c, arrays, encryption

Running a simple encryption on a single `char` array. It doesn't seem to work when the array size is less than or equal to 1, even though only a single char is changing.

The below works because `yesCrypto[10]` is set to `10` (or > 1).

```
char noCrypto[] = "H";    //sets an array to hold unencrypted H
char yesCrypto[10];        //sets array to hold encrypted H

yesCrypto[0]=noCrypto[0]+1;              
//takes 'H' from noCrypto and turns it into an 'I' and moves it into yesCrypto.

printf("Encrypted string is '%s'\n", yesCrypto);        
//prints Encrypted version of 'H', 'I'
```

---

The below does not work because `yesCrypto[0]` is set to `0`, also does not work when set to `1`.

```
char noCrypto[] = "H";    //sets an array to hold unencrypted H
char yesCrypto[1];        //sets array to hold encrypted H

yesCrypto[0]=noCrypto[0]+1;              
//takes 'H' from noCrypto and turns it into an 'I' and moves it into yesCrypto.

printf("Encrypted string is '%s'\n", yesCrypto);        
//prints 'IH'
```

---

Side question: why is it printing IH when it is not working probably.

Comment: You can't define zero-length arrays.

Comment: If the array is set to 1, same result

Comment: What result? It won't even compile with zero length. And yes, strings have to be null-terminated.

Comment: char yesCrypto[0]; or char yesCrypto[1]; Same result

Comment: The only result from  `yesCrypto[0]` can be a compilation error.

Comment: For me char yesCrypto[0]; char yesCrypto[1]; equals IH

Comment: *takes 'H' from noCrypto and turns it into an 'I' and moves it into yesCrypto.* That is a non-portable assumption about the character set in use.

Answer (score 3):

Code is attempting to print a character array that is not a *string* using `"%s"`.

`yesCrypto[]` is not certainly *null character* terminated.

```
char yesCrypto[10];
yesCrypto[0] = noCrypto[0]+1; 
printf("Encrypted string is '%s'\n", yesCrypto); // bad
```

Instead, limit printing  or append a *null character*.

```
// 1 is the maximum number of characters to print
printf("Encrypted string is '%.*s'\n", 1, yesCrypto);
// or 
yesCrypto[1] = '\0'; 
printf("Encrypted string is '%s'\n", yesCrypto);
```

---

OP's 2nd code is just bad as object arrays of length 0 lack defined behavior.

```
// bad
char yesCrypto[0];
```

---

OP's edited post uses `char yesCrypto[1];`.  In that case use

```
yesCrypto[0] = noCrypto[0]+1; 
printf("Encrypted string is '%.*s'\n", 1, yesCrypto);
// or 
printf("Encrypted character is '%c'\n", yesCrypto[0]);
```

---

Fundamentally, printing encrypted data as a *string* is a problem as the encrypted character array may contain a *null character* in numerous places and a *string* requires a *null character* and ends with the first one.

Answer (score 2):

In the first case, you're supplying an array (as an argument to `%s`) which is not null-terminated.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §7.21.6.1,

> `s`
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial
>   element of an array of character type.<sup>280)</sup> **Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character.** If the
>   precision is specified, no more than that many bytes are written. **If the
>   precision is not specified or is greater than the size of the array, the array shall
>   contain a null character.**

In this case, `yesCrypto` being an automatic local array and left uninitialized, the contents are indeterminate, so there's no guarantee of a null being present in the array. So the usage causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

What you're seeing in the second case is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), too.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.7.6.2

> In addition to optional type qualifiers and the keyword static, the `[` and `]` may delimit
>   an expression or `*`. If they delimit an expression (which specifies the size of an array), the
>   expression shall have an integer type. **If the expression is a constant expression, it shall
>   have a value greater than zero.** [...]

So, the later code (containing `char yesCrypto[0];`) has Constraints violations, it invokes UB.

---

*A note on why this might **not** produce a compilation error:*

*[`gcc` does have an extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Zero-Length.html) which supports zer-length arrays, but the use case is very specific and since `C99`, the "flexible array member" is a standadized choice over this extension.*

---

Finally, for

> *...also does not work when set to 1....*

will lack the space for a null-terminator, raising the same issue as in the very first case. To put it in simple words, to make a `char` array behave like a *string* containing `n` elements, you need

- size of the array to be `n+1`
- index `n` to contain a null character (`'\0'`).